# If I mount a portable hard drive as a folder in Windows 10, can I still use that drive as a portable drive on another computer?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, mount, portable-harddrive

I'm running out of space on my desktop computer's hard drive, mostly due to my photos and Lightroom catalog.  I would like to move the photos and catalog to an external drive, but would still like it to look like a folder in Windows 10 so that it will still be backed up to OneDrive.
But I would also like to be able to use the external drive on my laptop to edit photos. If I mount it on the desktop can I still use it as a portable drive (unplug from desktop and plug into laptop)?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. But just to make sure I understand, if the drive is showing up as a folder, what is the process to dismount it?

Comment: *"If the drive is showing up as a folder, what is the process to dismount it?* - Where is it showing up as a folder? Lightroom? OneDrive?

Comment: It would be showing up in OneDrive and would contain my photos and my lightroom catalog. So I would like to be able to use it on my desktop and laptop, but I don't know how to safely dismount a drive that looks like a folder to ensure it doesn't get out of sync.

Answer (score 3):

Unplugging the drive requires for it to be dismounted first.

If you use it on another computer without dismounting first,
you risk the meta-data on the disk getting out of sync with the version
stored in the computer memory.

Mount the disk again after plugging it in.

Comment: small clarification: "unmount" = windows' "safely remove hardware" or "right-click external drive> eject"

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  But just to make sure I understand, if the drive is showing up as a folder, what is the process to dismount it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Mount settings are stored by the OS, not in the filesystem that's being mounted.

Answer (score 1):

> If I mount it on the desktop can I still use it as a portable drive
> (unplug from desktop and plug into laptop)?

Generally yes. Just do not use My Documents for the folder on the laptop and it should work fine.

Just properly disconnect the drive before using it on different computers. Do this each time.

I use C:\temp or like folder to share USB drives between computers and they share fine.